# How can I print something, and then call a function with a print on the same line?

Tags: python, printing

In Python I have a function that prints something. I want to print something beforehand on the same line.

So, I use the following code

```
print 'The hand is', displayHand(hand)

def displayHand(hand):

    for letter in hand.keys():
        for j in range(hand[letter]):
             print letter,              # print all on the same line
    print                               # print an empty line
```

What happens however is that the print within the function is called by the print outside the function.

How can I print an opening string, and then call my function?

Comment: Please provide a sample input and expected output

Answer (score 5):

Rename `displayHand` to `renderHand` and have it return a string.

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided by @zmbq with returning is the obvious and proper one but if you still want your way you can use newer `print`, assuming you are using python >= 2.6

```
from __future__ import print_function
print("Something", end="")
```

With that you can print without `\n`. 
So basically you can do then:

```
print("The hand is", end="")
displayHand(hand)
```

And in the function:

```
print("letter", end="")
```

Answer (score 0):

For 2.x:

```
print 'The hand is', 
displayHand(hand)
print
```

For 3.x:

```
print('The hand is', end="")
displayHand(hand)
print()
```

The better method is to move printing of 'The hand is' into the function itself.